# Scribe OAuth Java Google Calendar api. NO Client libraries

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I've some code for interacting with dropox. Here it is:

```
package rest;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.builder.api.DropBoxApi;
import org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

// Step 1: Create Dropbox Account
// Step 2: Create Application (https://www.dropbox.com/developers)

public class DropBoxRestClient {
    // Access codes #1: per application used to get access codes #2 
    private static final String API_APP_KEY = "NOT_OF_YOUR_CONCERN";
    private static final String API_APP_SECRET = "NOT_OF_YOUR_CONCERN";

    // Access codes #2: per user per application
    private static final String API_USER_TOKEN = "NOT_OF_YOUR_CONCERN";
    private static final String API_USER_SECRET = "NOT_OF_YOUR_CONCERN";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                .provider(DropBoxApi.class)
                                .apiKey(API_APP_KEY)
                                .apiSecret(API_APP_SECRET)
                                .build();

        try {
            if ( API_USER_TOKEN.equals("") || API_USER_SECRET.equals("") ) {
                System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
                Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
                System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
                System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
                System.out.println("Press enter when done.");
                System.out.print(">>");
                Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
                Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                System.out.println("Define API_USER_TOKEN: " + accessToken.getToken());
                System.out.println("Define API_USER_SECRET: " + accessToken.getSecret());
                System.exit(0);
            }

            Token accessToken = new Token( API_USER_TOKEN, API_USER_SECRET);

            listFiles(service, accessToken);
            addFile("Hangover.txt", service, accessToken);
            //listFiles(service, accessToken);
            //deleteFile("teste.txt", service, accessToken);
            //listFiles(service, accessToken);

        } catch(ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(OAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void listFiles(OAuthService service, Token accessToken) throws ParseException {
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/");
        request.addQuerystringParameter("list", "true");
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();

        System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSE: =============");
        System.out.println(response.getCode());

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        String jsonAll = response.getBody();
        Object obj = parser.parse(jsonAll);

        JSONObject jsonAllObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String jsonItem = gson.toJson(jsonAllObj);

        System.out.println(jsonItem);
        System.out.println("END RESPONSE ===============");

        JSONObject rj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(response.getBody());
        JSONArray contents = (JSONArray) rj.get("contents");
        for (int i=0; i<contents.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) contents.get(i);
            String path = (String) item.get("path");
            System.out.println(" - " + path);
        }
    }

    private static void addFile(String path, OAuthService service, Token accessToken) throws ParseException {
        //TODO
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, 
                "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/" + path);

        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        request.addPayload("I love Cocain!");
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();

        System.out.println("Is File Created? Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSE: =============");
        System.out.println(response.getCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println("END RESPONSE ===============");

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        String jsonAll = response.getBody();
        Object obj = parser.parse(jsonAll);

        JSONObject jsonAllObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String jsonItem = gson.toJson(jsonAllObj);

        System.out.println(jsonItem);
    }

    private static void deleteFile(String path, OAuthService service, Token accessToken) throws ParseException {
        //TODO
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, 
                "https://api.dropbox.com/1/fileops/delete");
        request.addQuerystringParameter("root", "auto");
        request.addQuerystringParameter("path", path);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();

        System.out.println("Is File Created? Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSE: =============");
        System.out.println(response.getCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println("END RESPONSE ===============");

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        String jsonAll = response.getBody();
        Object obj = parser.parse(jsonAll);

        JSONObject jsonAllObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String jsonItem = gson.toJson(jsonAllObj);

        System.out.println(jsonItem);
    }
}
```

(This code works perfectly BTW)
What I am in pain to know is whether I can do a similar thing with google APIs using scribe. The thing is I can't find NO APP_KEY or APP_ID. I've created a project in Google Developers Console with credentials OAUTH as Web App and there are no such APP keys or IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, from https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2

> Go to the Google Developers Console.
>   Select a project, or create a new one.
>   In the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth. Next, click APIs. In the list of APIs, make sure all of the APIs you are using show a status of ON.
>   In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
>   Click Create new Client ID.
>   Select the appropriate Application Type for your project and enter any additional information required.

Comment: I want to make an app, which will be run in a web server (tomcat) and people connect to the web server. So, I've created a native application as a Google Chrome app. But there is no app_key or app_secret in it :(

Comment: If you are trying to make a Google Chrome app, then i think thats not possible to use the same scenario, check: https://developers.google.com/accounts/cookbook/platforms/Chrome

Comment: You could obtain a client id and client secret if you generate them for a web app.

Comment: yes but are [CLIENT id and secret] == [APP id and secret]? If yes, then I've been going around the roundabout X(

Comment: The answer is yes! :)